# Landscape table goes outside the page border

Tags: tables, landscape

I have a problem. I would like to display my data set in Latex. I only want to give a small excerpt. There are only a few columns.
The problem is that they are too long for the page. I have tried to reduce the font size. But that not work. Is there another option to display the whole columns without it going out of the page border?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% load before geometry
\usepackage[a4paper, left={2.5cm}, right={2cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
Hello. Please see below for the table.

\appendix
\chapter{Heading 1}
\label{chap:heading1}
    Here is some text. 
    
    \begin{landscape}
        {\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont
        \begin{table}[H]
            \caption{Table}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabularx}{20cm}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l||l|l|l|}
                
                
                \hline
                \textbf{orderDate} & 
                \textbf{zip} & 
                \textbf{city1} & 
                \textbf{countryISO} & 
                \textbf{isCancelled} & 
                \textbf{isDropShipment} & 
                \textbf{isExpress} & 
                \textbf{quantity} & 
                \textbf{...} & 
                \textbf{volumeInM3} & 
                \textbf{height} & 
                \textbf{length} & 
                \textbf{netWeight} & 
                \textbf{currentHub} 

                \\ \hline
            
                    
                asd & 
                asd & 
                asd &
                asd &  
                asd & 
                asd & 
                asd &
                asd & 
                asd & 
                asd &
                asd & 
                asd & 
                asd &
                asd 
    
                \\ \hline   
                
    
                
                
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
    }
    \end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If the value cells aren't too wide, you could rotate the table headers. But actually, I doubt that even then, there will be enough place for all the data in the table. Maybe you can split up the table in two smaller ones, each with half the columns.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Do you have an idea how to split the table into two halves and show that they are connected? And do you know why the font size doesn't work?

Comment: You might use the `\thead` command from `makecell` for the column heads to reduce the overall table size, as it enables line breaks in standard column types.

Comment: For me a font size change works. For example by putting `\small` before `\begin{tabularx}`

Comment: And if you split the table you might put an extra column with the row numbers in front of the others.